Secured Login in PowerApps
Objective: to create a secured case sensitive login in powerapps
Code:
First Attempt using "=": it gives a correct result even the correct password is aAaA and my input is aaaa or AAAA.
Set(Authorized,LookUp('FCMIS User Account', 'Email Address' = User().Email And Password = txtPassword.Text, {UserID: 'ID Number', NoOfRetry: 'No. of Retry'}));

Second Attempt using "exactin": it gives a correct result even the correct password is aAaA and my input is aAaAaa.
Set(Authorized,LookUp('FCMIS User Account', 'Email Address' exactin User().Email And Password exactin txtPassword.Text, {UserID: 'ID Number', NoOfRetry: 'No. of Retry'}));

